# Any theoretical reference for empirical equation for estimating oxygen saturation (% SpO2 = 110 - 25*R)?

Tags: sensor, photodiode, optoelectronics, biopotential, medical

The empirical equation used to estimate % SpO2 is based on the observation that the ratio of the red and infrared light absorbed by arterial blood (represented by R in the equation) varies linearly with oxygen saturation. This relationship can be derived from the Beer-Lambert law by assuming that the absorption of red and infrared light by oxyhemoglobin and deoxyhemoglobin can be approximated by linear functions.

The equation % SpO2 = 110 - 25 × R was derived from a series of empirical studies that measured the ratio of red to infrared light absorbed by arterial blood at different levels of oxygen saturation using pulse oximetry. The equation was found to be a good approximation of the true oxygen saturation over a wide range of values.

Is there any theoretical derivation of the equation % SpO2 = 110 - 25 × R?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to electrical engineering.

Comment: @vir characterizing sensors and transducer is not part of electrical engineering. Ok, in what high school?

Comment: I don't believe this is clearly off-topic to the point of voting to close, but I would suggest checking the scope and help centers of [chemistry.se] and [physics.se] to see whether this question may be a good fit for the scope and on-topic material there. Please note that questions should not be double-posted; if you choose to ask it elsewhere it may need to be closed/deleted here.